# TableViewController not displaying contacts

Tags: uitableview, contacts

I am very new to programming. I have a rough knowledge base of c++ but objective-c is entirely new to me.

I'm trying to implement a simple UITableViewController in an app where the user is prompted to add email recipients from their contacts list. The TableViewController loads but not the TableViewCell data. I've been scouring the iOS developer library and I find the information very cookie-cutter like. I found their example code and copy/pasted it to my ViewController files. I made the necessary changes to conform to my files, deleted some unnecessary calls and followed every answer I've found on this site that remotely deals with my issue… To no avail! Here's what I have so far:

.h

```
    @interface RecipientsViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

.m

```
#import "RecipientsViewController.h"
#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
enum TableRowSelected
{
    kUIDisplayPickerRow = 0,
    kUICreateNewContactRow,
    kUIDisplayContactRow,
    kUIEditUnknownContactRow
};

// Height for the Edit Unknown Contact row
#define kUIEditUnknownContactRowHeight 81.0


@interface RecipientsViewController () < ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate,ABPersonViewControllerDelegate,
ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate, ABUnknownPersonViewControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, assign) ABAddressBookRef addressBook;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *menuArray;

@end

@implementation RecipientsViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.title = @"Recipients";
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark Load views
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Create an address book object
    _addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
    self.menuArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    [self checkAddressBookAccess];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Address Book Access
    // Check the authorization status of our application for Address Book
    -(void)checkAddressBookAccess
    {
        switch (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus())
        {
                // Update our UI if the user has granted access to their Contacts
            case  kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
                [self accessGrantedForAddressBook];
                break;
                // Prompt the user for access to Contacts if there is no definitive answer
            case  kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined :
                [self requestAddressBookAccess];
                break;
                // Display a message if the user has denied or restricted access to Contacts
            case  kABAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            case  kABAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Privacy Warning"
                                                                message:@"Permission was not granted for Contacts."
                                                               delegate:nil
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
            }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    // Prompt the user for access to their Address Book data
    -(void)requestAddressBookAccess
    {
        RecipientsViewController * __weak weakSelf = self;

        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(self.addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)
                                                 {
                                                     if (granted)
                                                     {
                                                         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                             [weakSelf accessGrantedForAddressBook];

                                                         });
                                                     }
                                                 });
    }

    // This method is called when the user has granted access to their address book data.
    -(void)accessGrantedForAddressBook
    {
        // Load data from the plist file
        NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Menu" ofType:@"plist"];
        self.menuArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return [self.menuArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *aCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (aCell == nil)
    {
        // Make the Display Picker and Create New Contact rows look like buttons
        if (indexPath.section < 2)
        {
            aCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            aCell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        }
        else
        {
            aCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
            aCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
            aCell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
            // Display descriptions for the Edit Unknown Contact and Display and Edit Contact rows
            aCell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.menuArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"description"];
        }
    }

    // Configure the cell...

    return aCell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    switch (indexPath.section)
    {
        case kUIDisplayPickerRow:
            [self showPeoplePickerController];
            break;
        case kUICreateNewContactRow:
            [self showNewPersonViewController];
            break;
        case kUIDisplayContactRow:
            [self showPersonViewController];
            break;
        case kUIEditUnknownContactRow:
            [self showUnknownPersonViewController];
            break;
        default:
            [self showPeoplePickerController];
            break;
    }
}

#pragma mark TableViewDelegate method
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Change the height if Edit Unknown Contact is the row selected
    return (indexPath.section==kUIEditUnknownContactRow) ? kUIEditUnknownContactRowHeight : tableView.rowHeight;
}

#pragma mark Show all contacts
// Called when users tap "Display Picker" in the application. Displays a list of contacts and allows users to select a contact from that list.
// The application only shows the phone, email, and birthdate information of the selected contact.
-(void)showPeoplePickerController
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
    // Display only a person's phone, email, and birthdate
    NSArray *displayedItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonPhoneProperty],
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty],
                               [NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonBirthdayProperty], nil];


    picker.displayedProperties = displayedItems;
    // Show the picker
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark Display and edit a person
// Called when users tap "Display and Edit Contact" in the application. Searches for a contact named "Appleseed" in
// in the address book. Displays and allows editing of all information associated with that contact if
// the search is successful. Shows an alert, otherwise.
-(void)showPersonViewController
{
    // Search for the person named "Appleseed" in the address book
    NSArray *people = (NSArray *)CFBridgingRelease(ABAddressBookCopyPeopleWithName(self.addressBook, CFSTR("Appleseed")));
    // Display "Appleseed" information if found in the address book
    if ((people != nil) && [people count])
    {
        ABRecordRef person = (__bridge ABRecordRef)[people objectAtIndex:0];
        ABPersonViewController *picker = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init];
        picker.personViewDelegate = self;
        picker.displayedPerson = person;
        // Allow users to edit the person’s information
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        // Show an alert if "Appleseed" is not in Contacts
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                        message:@"Could not find Appleseed in the Contacts application"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

#pragma mark Create a new person
// Called when users tap "Create New Contact" in the application. Allows users to create a new contact.
-(void)showNewPersonViewController
{
    ABNewPersonViewController *picker = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
    picker.newPersonViewDelegate = self;

    UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:picker];
    [self presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:nil];
}

#pragma mark Add data to an existing person
// Called when users tap "Edit Unknown Contact" in the application.
-(void)showUnknownPersonViewController
{
    ABRecordRef aContact = ABPersonCreate();
    CFErrorRef anError = NULL;
    ABMultiValueRef email = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
    bool didAdd = ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(email, @"John-Appleseed@mac.com", kABOtherLabel, NULL);

    if (didAdd == YES)
    {
        ABRecordSetValue(aContact, kABPersonEmailProperty, email, &anError);
        if (anError == NULL)
        {
            ABUnknownPersonViewController *picker = [[ABUnknownPersonViewController alloc] init];
            picker.unknownPersonViewDelegate = self;
            picker.displayedPerson = aContact;
            picker.allowsAddingToAddressBook = YES;
            picker.allowsActions = YES;
            picker.alternateName = @"John Appleseed";
            picker.title = @"John Appleseed";
            picker.message = @"Company, Inc";

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:picker animated:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                            message:@"Could not create unknown user"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
    CFRelease(email);
    CFRelease(aContact);
}

#pragma mark ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate methods
// Displays the information of a selected person
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    return YES;
}

// Does not allow users to perform default actions such as dialing a phone number, when they select a person property.
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                                property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    return NO;
}

// Dismisses the people picker and shows the application when users tap Cancel.
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker;
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

#pragma mark ABPersonViewControllerDelegate methods
// Does not allow users to perform default actions such as dialing a phone number, when they select a contact property.
- (BOOL)personViewController:(ABPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
                    property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifierForValue
{
    return NO;
}


#pragma mark ABNewPersonViewControllerDelegate methods
// Dismisses the new-person view controller.
- (void)newPersonViewController:(ABNewPersonViewController *)newPersonViewController didCompleteWithNewPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    [self loadView];
}

#pragma mark ABUnknownPersonViewControllerDelegate methods
// Dismisses the picker when users are done creating a contact or adding the displayed person properties to an existing contact.
- (void)unknownPersonViewController:(ABUnknownPersonViewController *)unknownPersonView didResolveToPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

// Does not allow users to perform default actions such as emailing a contact, when they select a contact property.
- (BOOL)unknownPersonViewController:(ABUnknownPersonViewController *)personViewController shouldPerformDefaultActionForPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier
{
    return NO;
}
```

SORRY!!!  Not sure which sections of code are most relevant to the problem.

*** Given this much code is a little overwhelming for me to troubleshoot, I would greatly appreciate some help on this. I have no errors or issues showing up, the TableViewController loads. It only prompted the user to allow access to contacts a couple times and hasn't since. Even when the prompt did show, it never took me to the contacts on the simulator. I added contacts to the iOS simulator.

I sincerely appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't gone through all of your code but the problem u described occurs with me mostly when my array is empty, try putting NSLog of your array contents at the places where you are adding objets to it,In order to see if its count is greater than 0.

Comment: Thanks! Ok so I just did that and it returned a count of zero. How would I go about fixing this? Here's the code where I added the NSLog                                                                     - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Create an address book object
    _addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
    self.menuArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    [self checkAddressBookAccess];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    NSLog(@"Number of items in my array is: %lu", [_menuArray count]);
}

Answer (score 0):

What version of iOS are you using? That will determine if it will show up, if it is iOS 7 then you need permission to view the address book, thats the new thing they added.

This Link
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/QuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH2-SW1